# How do you keep the styling when you convert docx to pdf in Pandoc?

Tags: pdf, document, docx, styling, pandoc

I m using pandoc to convert docx file to pdf. 
Command I'm using for converting:

```
pandoc -o document.pdf document.docx
```

The problem is that after the convert, the styling disappears.

[image]

As you can see, The colors are missing and my table's position is moved to right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pandoc does not convert styles/layout/formatting.

From https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html:

> Because pandoc’s intermediate representation of a document is less expressive than many of the formats it converts between, one should not expect perfect conversions between every format and every other. Pandoc attempts to preserve the structural elements of a document, but not formatting details such as margin size.